# What does it mean to say "the random variable $X$ conditioned on $X$ being non-negative"?

Tags: probability-theory

I saw something like this:

> To extend the proof to all random  variables, let $\widehat{X}$ be the random variable $X$  conditioned on $X$ being non-negative. The distribution of $\widehat{X}$ is given by 
>   $$ F_{\widehat{X}}(x) = \frac {F_X(x)-  (1 -  F_X(0))}  {\mathbb P[X \ge 0]}, \quad  x \ge 0, $$
>   so that
>   $$dF_{X}(x) =\frac {dF(x)} {\mathbb P[X > 0]}.$$

The definition of $F_{\widehat{X}}(x)$ doesn't quite make sense for me. For example, when $x = 0$, we might have $F_{\widehat{X}}(x) < 0$, which does not match the definition of a distribution function. So, how should I interpret this? The about text is excerpted from [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2684633).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you're right: 
$$
  F_{\hat X}(0) = \frac{2F_X(x) - 1}{\Bbb P[X\geq 0]}
$$
which can easily be negative. I would rather condition as
$$
  \Bbb P[\hat X \in A] := \Bbb P[X\in A|X\geq 0],
$$
but I'm not sure that's what they mean cause in this case you get
$$
  F_{\hat X}(x) = \frac{F_X(x) - F_X(0)}{\Bbb P[X\geq 0]}, \quad x\geq 0
$$
which is indeed a CDF provided the denominator is non-zero. So perhaps it's a kinda typo in their case as they use $1-F_X(0)$ in place of $F_X(0)$.

Comment: Seems that this is the only possible explanation.